# Jenkins Jmeter Distributed Testing in Cloud

Tags: linux, maven, amazon-web-services, jenkins, jmeter

Current Setup
Master – Local Desktop
Slaves – 3 Linux machines in AWS
So before starting the performance test I will be starting the master agents from the slave machines by logging in manually and then start with the performance test.

Current Scenario
Right now have created a performance test framework using Jenkins-Jmeter-Maven integration. This Jenkins is currently hosted in my laptop so my laptop acts as the master. I am not sure how to jenkins can connect to slave jmeter linux machines without me logging in manually. Has anyone resolved this scenario ? can you please share the approach to resolve it ? 
I have tried using the following in pom.xml

```
<remoteConfig>
<startServersBeforeTests>true</startServersBeforeTests>
<serverList>1.2.3.4</serverList>
<stopServersAfterTests>true</stopServersAfterTests>
</remoteConfig>
```

but no use as I got this error

```
failure connecting to remote host: 1.2.3.4 java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 1.2.3.4; nested exception is: 
[info]  java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
[info] Failed to configure 1.2.3.4
[info] No remote engines were started.
```